# zend framework 3 routing conflict

Tags: routes, zend-framework3

I am facing problem in creating routing of detail page when we pass story title in url it is conflicting with our category url routing. So i need to validate {-storyid} at the end of the url.

example url:

http://localhost.tank.com/hindi/any-one-can-dance-on-table-before-me-1756838

http://localhost.tank.com/hindi/{category}

Comment: it's fast route right?

Answer (score 1):

In Zend Framework 2+ you can add a Priority to your routes. A higher priority means, your route will be proccessed before others. You can also give a negativ priority.

Your route in your module.config.php would need the priority key, something like this:

```
        'myroute' => [
            'priority' => 10,  // <-- route priority
            'type' => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/hindi[:/category]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'category' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action' => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```